# Multiple hybrid (automatic + manual) slideshows on one page

Tags: slideshow

I am trying to create about 11 different automatic/manual slideshows on one page and haven't got a scooby about how to do this. I want it to look like the first slideshow on this page https://www.jssor.com/demos/simple-fade-slideshow.slider but every time I try to put more than one of these on the page it doesn't work or messes up the divs and formatting.

I'm thankful for any help I can get to solve this mystery :)

This is the code:

```
<!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- Generator: Jssor Slider Maker -->
<!-- Source: https://www.jssor.com -->
<script src="js/jssor.slider-26.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: 1,
          $Cols: 1,
          $Align: 0,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        /*#region responsive code begin*/

        var MAX_WIDTH = 980;

        function ScaleSlider() {
            var containerElement = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode;
            var containerWidth = containerElement.clientWidth;

            if (containerWidth) {

                var expectedWidth = Math.min(MAX_WIDTH || containerWidth, containerWidth);

                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(expectedWidth);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        /*#endregion responsive code end*/
    };
</script>
<style>
    /* jssor slider loading skin spin css */
    .jssorl-009-spin img {
        animation-name: jssorl-009-spin;
        animation-duration: 1.6s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }

    @keyframes jssorl-009-spin {
        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        to {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }


    .jssorb051 .i {position:absolute;cursor:pointer;}
    .jssorb051 .i .b {fill:#fff;fill-opacity:0.5;}
    .jssorb051 .i:hover .b {fill-opacity:.7;}
    .jssorb051 .iav .b {fill-opacity: 1;}
    .jssorb051 .i.idn {opacity:.3;}

    .jssora051 {display:block;position:absolute;cursor:pointer;}
    .jssora051 .a {fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:360;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .jssora051:hover {opacity:.8;}
    .jssora051.jssora051dn {opacity:.5;}
    .jssora051.jssora051ds {opacity:.3;pointer-events:none;}
</style>
<div id="jssor_1" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:980px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-009-spin" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
        <img style="margin-top:-19px;position:relative;top:50%;width:38px;height:38px;" src="img/spin.svg" />
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:980px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/001.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/002.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/003.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/004.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/005.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/006.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/007.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/008.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/009.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/010.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/011.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="170.00">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/012.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
    <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb051" style="position:absolute;bottom:12px;right:12px;" data-autocenter="1" data-scale="0.5" data-scale-bottom="0.75">
        <div data-u="prototype" class="i" style="width:16px;height:16px;">
            <svg viewbox="0 0 16000 16000" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
                <circle class="b" cx="8000" cy="8000" r="5800"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
    <div data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora051" style="width:55px;height:55px;top:0px;left:25px;" data-autocenter="2" data-scale="0.75" data-scale-left="0.75">
        <svg viewbox="0 0 16000 16000" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
            <polyline class="a" points="11040,1920 4960,8000 11040,14080 "></polyline>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div data-u="arrowright" class="jssora051" style="width:55px;height:55px;top:0px;right:25px;" data-autocenter="2" data-scale="0.75" data-scale-right="0.75">
        <svg viewbox="0 0 16000 16000" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
            <polyline class="a" points="4960,1920 11040,8000 4960,14080 "></polyline>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">jssor_1_slider_init();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to get it work.

## 1. Specify unique `id` for each slider.

If the first one is `<div id="jssor_1" ...`, the second can be `<div id="jssor_2" ...`

## 2. Remove `id` attribute when initialize a slider.

```
var jssor_1_element = document.getElementById("jssor_1");
jssor_1_element.removeAttribute("id");
var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$(jssor_1_element, jssor_1_options);
```

Comment: Thank you! If I change the div name do I have to repeat the javascript code for each slideshow? I did this and only the last one works.

Comment: How do I write the JS code so that it includes all slideshows in one script? And if I use your second option where do I put it? Thank you

Comment: With the first option, replace all `jssor_1` with `new_id` for every slider. Should repeat javascript code for each slideshow.

Comment: With the second option, find the line var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$..., remove it and insert the 3 line codes above. No need to  repeat javascript code for each slideshow.